# Application not whitelisted

Tags: android, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been testing the Push notifications and notifications in xamarin.android application using Firebase Cloud Messaging, and am successfully receiving the notifications, however for the first time the applications starts normally, and then if I kill it by swiping from the recent applications then open it again, it wont open and says Application has stopped
Stack Trace is

```
    Time    Device Name Type    PID Tag Message
    08-20 18:54:40.467  Motorola XT1254 Debug   18661   DataOffloadReceiver  
    start DataOffloadIntentService..
    08-20 18:54:40.475  Motorola XT1254 Debug   18661    
    DataOffloadIntentService    Parse launched package name
    08-20 18:54:40.475  Motorola XT1254 Debug   18661    
    DataOffloadIntentService    Package details = #Intent;action=android.intent.action.MAIN;category=android.intent.category.LA UNCHER;launchFlags=0x10200000;component=com.pntesting.app/md57c407f2cc00598a36da38af2c395e21d.MainActivity;l.profile=0;end
   08-20 18:54:40.475   Motorola XT1254 Debug   18661   DataOffloadIntentService    Package name = com.pntesting.app
08-20 18:54:40.476  Motorola XT1254 Debug   18661   DataOffloadIntentService    Has INTERNET permission, check if whitelisted
08-20 18:54:40.478  Motorola XT1254 Debug   18661   DataOffloadIntentService    already on Wifi, do not offload
08-20 18:54:40.478  Motorola XT1254 Debug   18661   DataOffloadIntentService    Not whitelisted
08-20 18:54:40.478  Motorola XT1254 Debug   18661   DataOffloadIntentService    Offload not required, ignore the intent
08-20 18:54:40.466  Motorola XT1254 Debug   18661   DataOffloadReceiver  
   Received broadcast intentcom.android.launcher3.action.LAUNCH
```

I do not know what is meant by this as I already have `INTERNET` permission in my manifest and there is no error or exception
Thanks in Advance.